# Linear and angular speeds of a train

Tags: kinematics, velocity, linear-algebra, angular-velocity

I am using Radar sensor in a train.

Sensor is in the front part of the train to detect object and avoid collision.

It needs vehicle motion data to calculate objects longitudional and lateral speeds.

Vehicle motion data is composed of linear and angular velocities.

In a straight line the train will have only linear speed (v in +x axis for example)

Then when performing a curve does it continue to be v in magnitude but some part of it in the +x and some part of it in the +y axis?  (ignoring curve resistance).

Or it does get linear speed?

I am having difficulties to understand angular velocity concept in vehicles.

Comment: How is the _x_ and _y_ axis defined with relation to the train? Are you riding the train, or taking measurements from a stationary point? Please edit the question to make it clear what you are asking because your question isn't clear at all at this point.

Comment: Sensor is in the front part of the train to detect object and avoid collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then when performing a curve does it continue to be v in magnitude but some part of it in the +x and some part of it in the +y axis? (ignoring curve resistance).

The answer is no. An object following a path has velocity tangent to the path *always*. Even if the path is curved the velocity vector is tangent to the path. If it weren't it would deviate away from the path.

If you find the radius of curvature $r$, then the speed $v$ and the yaw rate $\omega$ are related by $$ v = \omega\, r$$

Similarly, the tangential acceleration $\dot{v}$ is $$ \dot{v} = \dot{\omega}\, r$$ 
The transverse acceleration is found by

$$ a = \omega^2\ r $$

In vector form, when the path at some instant has tangential direction $\hat{e}$ and normal direction $\hat{n}$ the decomposition of velocity and acceleration is

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \vec{v} & = v\,\hat{e} \\
  \vec{a} & = \dot{v} \,\hat{e} + \frac{v^2}{r}\, \hat{n}
\end{aligned} $$